# Segmentation fault when using recursive sum operation

Tags: c, recursion, sum, segmentation-fault

I'm having an issue using two different recursive sum methods, where at some point both fail and return a segmentation fault error. The first, sum_a only fails on high values, passed 260000, which i do not know why, and the second sum_b always fails. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

The execution is done as follows : ./sum a x

Where x is the number of recursions wanted for the SUM(1:x) and a is either a or b

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned count=0;

void signal_segv_handler(int sig) {
    char s[50];
    sprintf(s, "Segmentation fault! count=%u\n", count);
    write(2, s, strlen(s));
    _exit(1);
}

unsigned long long *sum_b(unsigned long long x) {
    unsigned long long *s;
    count++;
    if (x>0)
        *s = *sum_b(x - 1) + x;
    else
        *s = 0;
    return s;
}

unsigned long long sum_a(unsigned long long x) {
    count++;
    if (x>0)
        return sum_a(x - 1) + x;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    unsigned long long x;
    unsigned long long *sum_result;
    char result[100];

    static char stack[SIGSTKSZ];
    stack_t ss = {
        .ss_size = SIGSTKSZ,
        .ss_sp = stack,
    };
    struct sigaction sa = {
        .sa_handler = signal_segv_handler,
        .sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK
    };
    sigaltstack(&ss, 0);
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, 0);

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Please specify the sum function to use (a or b) and the target number of integers to sum.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    x = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "a") == 0)
        sprintf(result, "sum_a = %llu for x=%llu, count=%u \n", sum_a(x), x, count);
    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "b") == 0) {
        sum_result = sum_b(x);
        sprintf(result, "sum_b = %llu for x=%llu, count=%u \n", sum_result, x, count);
        free(sum_result);
    }
    else {
        printf("error: function must be a or b\n");
        return -1;
    }

    write(1, result, strlen(result));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sum_a fails because of stackoverflow. Your method stack adds more and more methods till it reaches the limit.

Comment: @Thomas thanks but what is the limit? why is it always around 260000 and how could i fix that?

Comment: I don't know the limit... I think you can change the limit in your IDE...

Comment: But why are you doing it with recursion? It is just a sum... So a usual loop would also work

Comment: But why are you doing it with recursion? It is just a sum... So a usual loop would also work

Comment: @Thomas i'm trying to understand how recursion works with regards to memory space in c on linux systems and so using a sum insures i won't fail the actual sum part and will only have the recursion problems

Comment: `unsigned long long *s;` is never initialized and points to memory you do not own.

Comment: Note: `sprintf(s, "Segmentation fault! count=%u\n", count);` You try to avoid printf(), but sprintf() is not signal-safe, either.

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned long long *sum_b(unsigned long long x) {
    unsigned long long *s; <------
    count++;
    if (x>0)
        *s = *sum_b(x - 1) + x;
    else
        *s = 0;
    return s;
}
```

You are using an uninitialized pointer without any mem allocation to store the sum results.

Answer (score 0):

Both sum_a and sum_b cause stack overflow when their iterations consume more memory than available in the stack. Seems like the stack size for your program is 8192KB(you may check it in the console with `ulimit -s`), one sum_a iteration consumes 32 bytes, and sum_b needs 48 bytes(because of more variables than in sum_a - `unsigned long long *s;`, and probably 16 byte stack aligning I'm not sure), so they owerflow the stack on ~260k and ~170k iteration respectively.

But sum_b has another point of segfault, here `*s = *sum_b(x - 1) + x;` and here `*s = 0;`
this is assigning to an uninitialized pointer (wild pointer, which points to a random memory address). It happens if no stack overflow took place of course(in that case assignment operation in this lines is never reached).

Some remarks not relevant to the question:

1. You allocate alt stack on the main stack, if which is overflown, your handler is in a bad stance, it still may work in some situations, but you should change `static char stack[SIGSTKSZ];` to malloc function.
2. You should avoid using not signal-safe functions in the signal handler, the list of functions you may find in the signal-safety man.
3. This line is probably not necessary, you may remove it `sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);`
4. Another segfault: `free(sum_result);` You should always balance a malloc with a call to free.